# django annotate даёт неожиданный результат

Tags: python, django

есть три модели (максимально упрощённо):

```
class GoodsModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=123)


class ImagesModel(models.Model):
    goods = models.ForeignKey(GoodsModel, related_name='goods_images', 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=123)


class OffersModel(models.Model):
    goods = models.ForeignKey(GoodsModel, related_name='offers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

В GoodsModel одна запись.
В ImagesModel две записи, связанные с одной записью в GoodsModel.
В OffersModel три записи связанные с одной записью GoodsModel и со значением quantity = 1 во всех случаях

Почему запрос

```
GoodsModel.objects.annotate(num_images=models.Count('goods_images')).filter(num_images__gt=0).annotate(offers_count=(models.Sum('offers__quantity')))[0].offers_count
```

даёт результат 6?

так же, если добавлять записи в таблицу ImagesModel, результат кратно увеличивается. т.е. если в таблице ImagesModel 3 записи и в таблице OffersModel 3 записи, результат будет 9.
но это не самое странное. даже если не использовать фильтр из аннотированного поля, а написать что-то вроде .filter(id=1), то результат всё равно кратный количеству записей в ImagesModel.

```
GoodsModel.objects.annotate(num_images=models.Count('goods_images')).filter(id=1).annotate(offers_count=(models.Sum('offers__quantity')))[0].offers_count  # 9
```

но если убрать .annotate(num_images=models.Count('goods_images')), то результат становится верным.

```
GoodsModel.objects.filter(id=1).annotate(offers_count=(models.Sum('offers__quantity')))[0].offers_count # 3
```

Почему вообще в этом случае annotate влияет на результат?

upd:
даже запрос

```
GoodsModel.objects.filter(goods_images__isnull=False).annotate(total_offers=Count('offers'))
```

даёт неправильный результат.

upd2:
ChatGPT подсказала такой вариант. но он мне кажется слишком усложнённым. хоть и работает, но  запросы стали медленнее в два раза.

```
offers_count_subquery = OffersModel.objects.filter(goods=OuterRef('pk'), quantity__gt=0).values('goods').annotate(
    total_offers=Sum('quantity')
).values('total_offers')[:1]

goods_with_images_and_offer_count = GoodsModel.objects.annotate(
    images_count=Count('goods_images'),
    total_offers=Subquery(offers_count_subquery)
).filter(images_count__gt=0)
```

всё же интересно почему так неадекватно работает простой запрос...